# Cocoa resizing WebView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview, interface-builder

still new to Mac programming, having an issue with WebViews

My view controller declares two Outlets

```
@property IBOutlet NSView *mainView;
@property IBOutlet WebView *webView;
```

These are synthesised and linked up to an NSView and a WebView respectivally. The webView sits inside the NSView (which in turn is inside a ScrollView). I have imported WebKit headers.

When I instantiate my view controller and do this

```
[viewController.mainView setFrameSize:NSMakeSize(1000, 1000)];
```

My NSView balloons to 1000x1000, brilliant. However, when I do this:

```
[viewController.webView setFrameSize:NSMakeSize(1000,1000)];
```

I see absolutely no change. Nor does it throw an error. What gives?